# Is it correct to say "among the best universities to study history at"?

Tags: prepositions

I'm writing my personal statement for university, and I can't find an answer about whether the following sentence is grammatically correct:

> Being among the best universities to study history **at**, Cambridge ...

My reasoning for including "at" in this sentence is that it feels natural to say "I study history **at** Cambridge.". However, including "at" makes the sentence very unnatural to read.

Comment: Would *for studying history* work for you? BTW *among* will do you in, as no Cambridge Admissions folk will be flattered to be so labeled.

Answer (score 2):

The grammatical problem with which you are struggling is known as a dangling or stranded preposition. In order to avoid these in English, we're sometimes forced to use sentence constructions that also seem unnatural to us, such as my first sentence here. "History at Cambridge" is grammatically correct, but when you say "to study history at", Cambridge has been divided from its preposition by the comma because they are now in two different clauses. People's feelings about how objectionable this problem is vary. In the case of your university application, it's probably best avoided. Try to keep your objects directly behind their prepositions when your purpose requires formality. A more correct construction would be "Cambridge, being among the best universities at which to study history", but that is very awkward. Yosef's comment sounds like a great suggestion. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_stranding

Comment: I was about to vote to close the question because it is (almost) mere proofreading. Your answer persuades me otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, Anton. I'm happy to have found this forum.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried that your audience considers preposition stranding to be wrong ([not all do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_stranding#The_Debate_about_P-stranding)), move it:

> *Being among the best universities at which to study history, Cambridge . . .*

Also, I agree with Yosef Baskin’s comment: You might want to let them know that they *are* the best, not *among* the best.

Comment: "One of the best" not "among the best".

Comment: 'Being among the best universities to study history at' sounds more awkward than some stranded-preposition strings.